# whether they are complete metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

$S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}: 2x^2\cos{1\over x}=1\}$

$T=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:2x^2\cos{1\over x}\le 1\}\cup\{0\}$

I need to tell whether they are complete metric space under usual metric. As they  are closed subsets of complete metric space $\mathbb{R}$, so they are complete. Am I right?

Edit: $S=f^{-1}\{1\},T=\{0\}\cup f^{-1}(-\infty,1]$  $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Can you prove that $S$ and $T$ are closed?

Comment: @IanColey inverse image of closed set under continuos map

Comment: $2x^2\cos(1/x)$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: I know $\lim_{x\to 0}\cos{1\over x}$ does not exists. hence not continuos but could you tell me why $x^2\cos(1/x)$ is not?

Comment: If it's continuous then you must have $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$ at every point.

Comment: Oh ho..yah yah..so what can  be said about $T$?I am not sure

Comment: How do you get that $S$ is closed? $0 \notin S$.

Comment: ah!!! now totally confused.. I thought $f$ is continous and applied defiition, now its seems both are not closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can define the function:
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2\cos\frac{1}{x}&x\neq 0\\
0&x=0
\end{cases}
$$

We can see that as $x\to 0$, $|g(x)|\leq |x|^2$, so $g(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$. Therefore $g$ is continuous since it is continuous at $0$ and outside of $0$.  Now $S=g^{-1}(\{1\})$, and since $g$ is continuous, the preimage of a closed set is closed. Additionally, $T$ is the preimage of $(-\infty,1]$, so it too should be closed.

(thanks for the catch below)

Comment: Why preimage of $[0,1]$ and not $(-\infty,1]$? The function $g$ can attain negative values.

Comment: You're quite right. I forgot about the negative sign on the cosine.

Comment: @SenoreBunuel I think Ian's solution is correct.

Comment: @IanColey    very nice solution...